# hadoop map separate when MR is running

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to hadoop.
I want to check that I've studied and question about a hypothesis.

This is the idea.
For example, 5 nodes in hadoop, 1 should be master.
Each slave nodes has got 1 MR task. - configured in conf/mapred-site.xml.

This is I've studied that I've run hadoop examples.
MR is automatically decide map tasks number in word count.

> Q1. Is it connected with block size option or something else?

It could be changed by properties. When I was running PI and random text writer, it was changed.

> Q2. Is it possible to change any other MR program? I mean, in word count, properties effects the map task's number.

This is another idea.
In this case, I got 4 slaves, 2 map tasks. It means, it can run 2 nodes at once.

It's just hypothesis.
JT makes 2 map tasks and estimating time is over 1 hour.
It's no good for the performance. 2 nodes aren't running. If use 4 nodes for map, it could be faster.  I want to separate existing maps at job runtime.

> Q3. A possibility of this hypothesis. If it can, let me know how to get references.

I'm waiting for your advice.

thank you all.

Comment: take a look at this:
http://yaseminavcular.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-set-number-of-maps-with-hadoop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, it is related to block size and number of files you have, 
For example, you have 3,7 gb data and you have 512 mb data size it creates 8 map tasks for this. Furthermore, it is directly related to your file number in your input directory. For each file in your directory, at least one map task is created. Also you can increase (yes, this means you cannot decrease) the map task programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the answers.

Firstly, I didn't think about the number of files. Actually I was curious about split maps when MR is running in JVM. I tried to find some infos, it was no use.

Well now, I know about the importance of hadoop configuration especially mapred-site.xml for MR, I'm gonna study more about configurations.

thank you again.